# Finding most frequent combinations

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 columns, ID number and brand:

```
X1     X2
1234   A89
1234   A87
1234   A87
1234   A32
1234   A27
1234   A27
1235   A12
1235   A14
1235   A14
1236   A32
1236   A32
1236   A27
1236   A12
1236   A12
1236   A14
1236   A89
1236   A87
1237   A99
1237   A98
```

I want to find the top 3 brand combinations that occur together most frequently with regard to id number:

```
A89, A87
A32, A27
A12, A14
```

I tried:
    library(dplyr)

```
 df %>% 
  group_by(X1,X2) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(X1) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

But it doesn't work correctly. I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it in base R. We split `X2` by `X1` and then get combination of two values for each subgroup. Then we grab the three most common ones.

```
with(data.frame(table(unlist(lapply(split(df$X2, df$X1), function(x)
    combn(unique(x), min(2, length(x)), paste, collapse = "-"))))),
    as.character(Var1[head(order(Freq, decreasing = TRUE), 3)]))
#[1] "A12-A14" "A32-A27" "A89-A87"
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(X1 = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 
1235L, 1235L, 1235L, 1236L, 1236L, 1236L, 1236L, 1236L, 1236L, 
1236L, 1236L, 1237L, 1237L), X2 = c("A89", "A87", "A87", "A32", 
"A27", "A27", "A12", "A14", "A14", "A32", "A32", "A27", "A12", 
"A12", "A14", "A89", "A87", "A99", "A98")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
```

Comment: I tried this, but am having trouble with my full dataset. I'm getting the error "Error in combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse = "-") : n < m". I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: Realise this is old, but I've been adapting it and hit the same issue - for the benefit of anybody else who gets stuck: you need at least 2 unique X2 values ('brands'  in the original post) for every grouping variable (X1 in original post). You can achieve this by initially subsetting with `df = df[sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `which.max` but stick with standard `dplyr`

library(dplyr)

```
df %>% 
  group_by(X1,X2) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(X2) %>% # or X1? Unclear which is your sorting variable
  top_n(3, X2) %>% # Returns 3 rows for each, can be changed / also could be X1
  select(-n)
```

Note: `top_n` will include more than `3` rows if there are ties

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R method using `tapply` to group and `combn` with `paste` to get pairwise combinations.

```
names(tail(sort(table(unlist(tapply(df$X2, df$X1,
                                FUN=function(x) combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse="-"))))),
           3))
[1] "A12-A14" "A32-A27" "A89-A87"
```

`combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse="-")` unique pairs and pastes them together. `tapply` performs this by group and returns a list. `unlist` turns this into a vector, and `table` calculates frequencies. These frequencies are sorted smallest to largest, and we grab the last 3 with `tail`. `names` extracts the pair rather than the count from `table`.

Comment: this is working for my smaller dataset, but not for my larger one because of the error n < m. I suspect I need to put in an exception for length that are less than 'm'... what do you think?

Comment: My guess is that is this message is from the `combn`, so you can change `function(x) combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse="-")` to `function(x) if(length(x) > 1) combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse="-") else NA` and it should run without error.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution. First we generate all combinations of 2 of X2 by group (X1), and then use dplyr to aggregate and subset the top 3.

```
combinations = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(split(df,df$X1), function(x) 
    {t(combn(unique(x$X2),2))})))

combinations %>% 
group_by(V1,V2) %>% 
summarize(n=n()) %>% 
arrange(-n) %>% 
.[1:3,]
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [3]
      V1     V2     n
  <fctr> <fctr> <int>
1    A12    A14     2
2    A32    A27     2
3    A89    A87     2
```