# R related question, How to find the most frequent pairs of variables?

Tags: r

I have a data frrame looking like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CrAT.png)

My goal is to find the most common pair of items, in this case (1 and 3)

I already tried this:

```
names(tail(sort(table(unlist(tapply(ol$ORDER_ID, ol$SKU_ID,
                FUN = function(x) if(length(x) > 1) combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse="-") else NA)))),
           3))
```

But I keep getting this error message, and I don't know how to fix it.

`Error in combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse = "-") : n < m`

Someone suggested

```
library(dplyr), then count(your_data, ORDER_ID, SKU_ID) %>% arrange(desc(n))
```

But it still gives me the same error message, another person refered me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809166/count-number-of-rows-within-each-group), but I struggle to see the relevance.

Comment: `library(dplyr)`, then `count(your_data, ORDER_ID, SKU_ID) %>% arrange(desc(n))`

Comment: I followed your advice, then put my code in, but the Error message stays the same `Error in combn(unique(x), 2, paste, collapse = "-") : n < m`

Comment: Yes, my code is an alternate method, not a fix for your method.

Comment: Ah, but I see I misunderstood your question. It would be really helpful if you should share some reproducible sample data. `dput()` is the easiest way to do this, something like `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. It's difficult to develop and test code based on a picture of data...

Comment: @GregorThomas I have transcribed the data in the picture into my answer.

Comment: I think [this is a possible duplicate, and d.b's answer looks applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491650/903061).

Comment: I tried that solution already, but it keeps giving me : `Error in combn(unique(x), min(2, length(x)), paste, collapse = "-") : 
  n < m`

Answer (score 0):

In base R you could do:

```r
tab <- table(ol$SKU_ID, ol$ORDER_ID)
as.numeric(combn(row.names(tab), 2)[,
                which.max(rowSums(apply(combn(row.names(tab), 2), 1, 
                         function(x) rowSums(tab[x,]))))])
#> [1] 1 3
```

---

**Data used**

```r
ol <- data.frame(
  ORDER_ID = c(111, 111, 121, 121, 121, 121, 131, 131, 141, 141, 141),
  SKU_ID   = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 9))
```

Comment: @ArvanTheil how large is your data frame? And how many unqiue values of `SKU_ID` are there?

Comment: @ArvanTheil so you have about 2 million possible unique pairs to assess on every row. That's almost a trillion different calculations. I didn't realise your data were so large. Can you break it down into chunks?

Comment: You mean to fragment the dataset into smaller parts?

Comment: @ArvanTheil yes.

Comment: That would probably be possible, but I am not sure to how many parts I would have to fragment it.